# OSX El Capitan local install Maximum upload file size: 2 MB But php.ini set to 64M

Tags: wp-admin, uploads, localhost, php.ini

Brand new site. Not MU. No matter what I do, I cannot get a file uploaded that exceeds 2MB. I'm running a localhost server with WordPress 4.3.1

I've modified both relevant settings in the the site's `php.ini` as:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
```

However, I'm still getting the message when trying to upload a plugin that's 2.5M

> The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in
>   php.ini.

Also, when I go to "Media > Add New", I get the message:

> Maximum upload file size: 2 MB.

My htaccess file is the default and has no mention of max upload size.

What gives? Is it a requirement to restart anything after modifying the site's php.ini? If so, I could not find a restart command on my phpmyadmin panel.

Comment: Do you have something related to upload_max_filesize in wp-config.php ?

Comment: Are you sure you set the correct php.ini? You may have set that for PHP running as CLI. Also why 4.3.1? The latest version is 4.7, you should update for security fixes

Comment: @Benoti nothing in wp-config about that

Comment: @Tom - I'm regression testing an issue

Comment: @Benoti I'd be happy to place something there but my sense is its overridden by some unseen global that I can't find.

Comment: You have to find the the right php.ini corresponding to the PHP version...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, there are two `php.ini` files, one for the local server and one for the site. You can change the site's `upload_max_filesize` to whatever you want, if the server's php-settings say it's 2 MB, that's it.

So, find the `php.ini` file of your server install and change the value. Then reboot.

Comment: There is no php.ini file at the server level. Searching finder for "php.ini" only yields one in each site. If I were to place one there, where should it reside?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if anything is hooked to the [`upload_size_limit` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upload_size_limit/).

This can be a hard one to track down. (I once used a plugin that set it to 1MB for reasons I never figured out. It took a *long* time to find the issue.)

Comment: It's a brand new  site with a fresh copy of WordPress. Why would this be set in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The first things to check is PHP.ini file.
The values of `upload_max_filesize`, `memory_limit` and `post_max_size` in the php.ini configuration file exactly.

All of these three settings limit the maximum size of data that can be submitted and handled by PHP.

Typically `post_max_size` and `memory_limit` need to be larger than `upload_max_filesize`